# Windows file access denied after re-install

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, permissions

The problem I am having is the following:

I re-installed my windows 8.1 a few days ago on my main drive (C:). But now I am unable to do anything more than creating folders on my data drive (E:). ( I did not reformat this drive after re-installation)

So to clear up at first I wasn't able to find any duplicate of this that solved the problem on my end:

- I am shown as administrator under windows.
- I disabled UAC.
- I took ownership of the drive and recursivly of its files with icacls, takeown and windows security GUI.
- I tried transfering ownership and all permission to my exact user.
- The drive is not enrcypted nor was it at any time.
- The drive is intact and has no corrupted files on it that I am aware of.
- I can browse and read all files.

Comment: Use icacls to grant **everyone** full access.

Comment: How exactly did you reinstall? Was it a Clean install?

Comment: complete clean install. Windows was on C: i did reformat this drive and then re-installed win

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Basically some directories on the drive were create on different OS versions some were even created back in the days of xp. So I had to first gain ownership of alle files takeown or GUI will do the trick here.

Then you have to modify permission based on what permission system was used on creating the files. First using icacls then also using the older cacls. Regarding cacls you have to account for spaces etc in paths and maybe go over some folders again specially modifing their permissions.